# Google Maps - How to remove Map Toolbar

Tags: java, android, google-maps

How can I remove those buttons?

[image]

Comment: please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You can get the [`UiSettings`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings) from your `GoogleMap` and then set these items to false.

The button that you want to remove is the `Map Toolbar`

> Sets the preference for whether the Map Toolbar should be enabled or disabled. If enabled, and the Map Toolbar can be shown in the current context, users will see a bar with various context-dependent actions, including 'open this map in the Google Maps app' and 'find directions to the highlighted marker in the Google Maps app'.

So you should remove it using [`setMapToolbarEnabled`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings.html#setMapToolbarEnabled(boolean))

Example :

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
```